# SSH - need to access multiple embedded servers from multiple clients, without having to update all the servers every time a new client is used

Tags: ssh

We will have multiple (eventually hundreds of) embedded servers going out in the field to client sites and coming back to our site.  We need to be able to securely log in to any server from any of multiple clients (laptops, tablets, etc.) both here and out in the field.

I'd prefer SSH (or equivalent) but with hundreds of servers if a new client is introduced (e.g. a laptop dies and we replace it) it will simply be impractical to generate a new key pair and update all the servers individually (many of which will be offsite and temporarily inaccessible) with the new public key.

Other than generating a single key pair and copying the private key to each client (an obvious no-no), is there a way to securely accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSH can be configured to accept certificates signed by a CA to authenticate both users and hosts.

Read the `CERTIFICATES` section from the [ssh-keygen(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1) manual page.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a bunch of key pairs ahead of time (more than you'll need), and push all of the public keys to the servers. Keep the extra private keys in a safe or in some similarly secure location, and issue them to clients as needed.

This still doesn't leave you with any way to revoke keys, though, which may or may not be a problem.